# How to avoid TclError if I want to update the results obtained from entries instantly?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to add two numbers and add them and update the result instantly without using a button.
I have written this code using `after()` to do that.
from tkinter import *

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

label1 = Label(root, text="1st number:")
label1.grid(row=0, column=0)

label2 = Label(root, text="2nd number:")
label2.grid(row=1, column=0)

first_no = IntVar()
second_no = IntVar()

entry1 = Entry(root, textvariable=first_no)
entry1.grid(row=0, column=1)

entry2 = Entry(root, textvariable=second_no)
entry2.grid(row=1, column=1)


def auto():
    try:
        S = first_no.get() + second_no.get()
        label3.config(text="Sum:  " + str(S))
        # call again after 100 ms
        root.after(100, auto)
    except TclError:
        print("there is an Error")

label3 = Label(root)
label3.grid(row=3, column=1)

auto()

root.mainloop()
```

The code works well. However, if we delete the numbers in the entries using the `delete` or `backspace` keyboards this error raises: `_tkinter.TclError: expected floating-point number but got ""`, and if I enter new values the code does not work anymore.
I wondered to know how I avoid this problem??

Comment: You would need to do at least the `.get()`s (and perhaps the entire computation) inside of a `try`...`except` statement, so that you can catch the error that happens when the value is not valid.

Comment: @jasonharper thank you for your reply. But how get back to the normal behavior of the code before raising the error?

Comment: When you catch the error, normal behavior won't be interrupted; you simply won't have a new value for the Label on that particular call to `auto()`.

Comment: @jasonharper I edited my code. in this way, the code doesn't show any error but still, after entering a new number, it cannot show the summation. Could you please let me know if this code is right?

Comment: I found the solution. I added another `root.after(100, auto)` under `exception TclError`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I added another `root.after(100, auto)` under `exception TclError`